# Trying to launch Craft CMS site on 1&1.co.uk and told I don't have permission. Any help why?

Tags: templating, url, error, installation

[image]

Does anyone know how to launch a Craft CMS site on 1&1.co.uk web hosting. I've uploaded my database, changed the siteUrl and uploaded the site with FTP but it's not working. I receive an error message (see image).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely a problem with permissions on your folders. You can find the right permissions here: https://craftcms.com/docs/installing#step-2-set-the-permissions

Comment: Craft says to set the permissions to 744. I was told by 1&1 to set my permissions to 604 but only on the files not the folders. My folders are currently 705.

Do you know if I should change all files and folders to 744?

Comment: Yes, set them to 744! I also had permission issues when setting up a Craft site on a 1&1 server (Germany, but I guess it's the same). Make sure to set it recursively, so that it applies to subfolders and contents. Note that it only needs this on the 3 folders that are listed.

Comment: The first number 7 basically says that the current user (that the server is running as) can perform read/write/execute on those folders, which it needs. When the first number is 6, it can only read and write, and it won't be able to execute the PHP scripts. The numbers 4 means only read access, which will then apply to any other users (the current user GROUP and public users respectively, to be exact). You can look for instance here to decipher what the numbers mean :-)  https://chmod-calculator.com/

Comment: You're amazing! Thank you so much. It was the permissions. Finally working now.

Comment: Great, happy to be of help! If you mark the answer as correct, then others with the same problem will see that the issue is resolved!

Answer (score 1):

I used to use 1and1 servers and this came up when my .htaccess wasn't set. Be sure to add the '.' to the beginning of the htaccess file name within the 'public' folder that comes with craft and you may even have to add 'RewriteBase /' to it too.

Comment: My htaccess has a '.' before it. I will try adding 'RewriteBase /' also.

Comment: Hey, the 'RewriteBase /'  was really helpful in removing the index.php from the url